# How to start ListTile halfway down the page?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a ListTile of cards going down my page but I don't have an AppBar in my app, so the ListTile starts at the top of the page. If I add padding, it adds it to each card in the ListView and then whilst I can position the cards lower in the page, I get huge gaps between them. Is there any way in which I can maintain the small gap that I would like in between the cards but simply have a larger gap at the top before the ListView begins? For reference, I pasted the code below. (Essentially it is a Todo list type app, so there is a FormField that pops ups from the bottom and you enter a task it appears on the card in the ListView.)

```
Widget _buildTodoList() {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('EEE d MMM').format(now);
  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if(index < _todoItems.length) {
        return ListTile(
          onLongPress: () => _promptRemoveTodoItem(index),
          title: Card(
              elevation: 1.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23.0),
              ),
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, 
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23.5, 27.5, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text("?", 
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                              ),
                      ),
          ),
          Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23.5, 58.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text("${_todoItems[index]}", 
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.black38,
                              ),
                      ),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 6.5, 20.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(formattedDate, 
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 11,
                                color: Colors.deepOrange[700],
                              ),
                      ),
                      ),
                      ),
          ],
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 380,
        ),
        ],
        ),
        ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correct, but if it's - I see a couple of solutions:

You can add padding to whole `ListView`

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0), child: ListView.builder(...),)
```

You can add empty item on first place in list:

```
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    return SizedBox(height: 200.0,);
  } else {
    // todo return your ListTile
  }
},
itemCount: _todoItems.length + 1,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice - that was exactly it, I still find the layouts in flutter a bit different to what I am used to so that helps a lot.